# how to print file containing text with ANSI escapes

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

I would like to print a file containing text with ANSI escapes.

Here is file content (generated with bash script):

```
\033[1m bold message example \033[0m
normal font message
```

- When printing file to screen in terminal, it works nice:

  ```
    cat example.txt
  ```

  shows:

  > **bold message example**
  >
  > normal font message
- But my problem when I try to send it to a printer:

  ```
    lp example.txt
  ```

  prints:

  > 1mbold message example2m
  >
  > normal font message

Is there a way to print this file correctly ? Maybe with groff (can be used to print a styled man page), but I did not manage to get anything efficient with it...

Comment: How was this file produced in the first place? And you probably mean `cat` instead of `echo` ....

Comment: Still, how was that file produced?

Comment: Then, improve your bash script to be able to generate something else... See my answer....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [a2ps](http://www.gnu.org/software/a2ps/) might be able to handle that (but I am not sure, you should try).

And I would rather suggest changing the way you get such a file with [ANSI escapes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) (that is, also provide some alternative output format).
I mean that the program producing such a file (or such an output) could instead produce a more printable output (perhaps by generating some intermediate form, e.g. LaTeX, or Lout, or groff or HTML format, then forking the appropriate command to print it. That program could also generate directly PDF thru [libharu](http://libharu.org/) or [poppler](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/), etc....)

Also, it might depend upon your printer, and the driver.

Comment: thanks, in fact that's what I am already using: ANSI escapes ;

a2ps does not seem to work too ...

Comment: I finally generated another output format (html), that can be easier to print